# About pass the params to print Mysql tablename use mysqldb issue?

Tags: python, mysql-python

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import time
import re
import urllib
import urllib2
import MySQLdb

hostip = raw_input("Input your sql Ip:")
username = raw_input("Input your sql username:")
password = raw_input("Input your password:")
dbname = raw_input("Input your dbname :")

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host = hostip, user = username, passwd = password, db = dbname)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("show tables")
alltable = cur.fetchall()
tablenames = []
for i in range(len(alltable)):
    for j in range(len(alltable[i])):
        tablenames.append(alltable[i][j])

print tablenames
```

Above is my code, need pass the input args to access the mysql connect, but i can't print the tables name use the program, can someone help me with that?
thank you very much !

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What is the program doing? What do you expect it to do?

Comment: After run it, need fill the raw_input and complete the mysqldb connect, and print the mysql table names, what's wrong with the params passing ?

Comment: My question was what the code you provide actually does when you run it (and therefore what it is doing wrong)

Comment: when i run it, i input the host, user, db, passwd, and print nothing.. ..

Comment: It prints nothing or it prints `[]`?

Comment: Thank you for replying, it prints nothing, is the params passing issue ? need to accept the raw_input args and print the list about mysql tables

Comment: How can it print literally nothing? Does it reach the line `print tablenames`? If so, it must print something (even if just `[]`). Does it throw an error?

Comment: when i run it in the terminal , the cursor just blink, and return nothing...no error

Comment: Please help me fix it... can you tell me the code problem ?

Comment: That's not possible. Are you sure this is the code you are running? The line `print tablenames` must print something, even if it's just `[]`.

Comment: Am i pass the hostip,user,dbname the right way ?

Comment: As far as I can tell, yes- stop focusing on it. Please add the line `print alltable` right after the line `alltable = cur.fetchall()` and tell me what happens then.

Comment: Why do you have all the imports that you are not using? Is this the entire program?

Comment: Thank you, i fixed it, cause the sql issues  -,-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have pasted part of the code that couldn't produce the error that you have stated. Here is the re-written version:

```
import MySQLdb
from getpass import getpass

hostip = raw_input("Input your sql Ip:")
username = raw_input("Input your sql username:")
password = getpass("Input your password:")
dbname = raw_input("Input your dbname :")

conn = MySQLdb.connect(hostip, username, password, dbname)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SHOW TABLES")
tablenames = [i[0] for i in cur.fetchall()]
print tablenames
```

Run this *and only this*.